# Выбрать данные с минимальной датой из связанной таблицы в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Попробую кратко объяснить суть проблемы, имеются две таблицы:

```
 `account`              `deposit`
+----+---------+       +----+------------+---------------------+-------+
| id | user_id |       | id | account_id | created_at          | value |
+----+---------+       +----+------------+---------------------+-------+
|  1 |       2 |       |  1 |          1 | 2020-06-01 15:51:37 | 50.00 |
|  2 |      12 |       |  2 |          1 | 2020-06-05 13:05:25 | 20.00 |
|  3 |      13 |       |  3 |          1 | 2020-06-05 13:36:11 | 20.00 |
|  4 |       2 |       |  4 |          2 | 2020-06-16 12:34:04 | 70.00 |
|  5 |       2 |       |  5 |          3 | 2020-06-22 07:20:57 | 50.00 |
|  6 |       2 |       |  6 |          4 | 2020-05-30 08:25:56 | 30.00 |
+----+---------+       +----+------------+---------------------+-------+
```

где `account_id` — это внешний ключ на столбец `id` в таблице `account`. Мне нужно получить для каждого `user_id` одну запись из таблицы `account`, которая имеет связанную запись с **наименьшей** датой `created_at` в таблице `deposit`.

Я пытался получить данные следующим запросом:

```sql
SELECT
    `account`.`id`,
    `account`.`user_id`,
    MIN(`deposit`.`created_at`) AS `date`
FROM `account`
INNER JOIN `deposit` ON `account`.`id` = `deposit`.`account_id`
GROUP BY `account`.`user_id`;
```

Что в итоге я получаю:

```
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | date                |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |       2 | 2019-05-30 08:25:56 |
|  2 |      12 | 2020-06-16 12:34:04 |
|  3 |      13 | 2020-06-22 07:20:57 |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

Но в первой строке в столбце `account.id` я ожидаю получить "**4**", т.к. именно этот счёт имеет связанную запись с наименьшей датой `created_at`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне переделать мой запрос, чтобы получить правильный результат.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Какая версия MySQL?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky 5.7.

Comment: как-то так https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8ff407bf626fc5f1839a454745cf18f6, но структура таблиц - ужас

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis спасибо, ваше решение работает. Оформите ваш sql-запрос, как ответ — я поставлю плюс и отмечу, как принятый. А по поводу структуры, многое делалось до меня, поэтому и приходится изощряться...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать запрос ниже, чтобы получить необходимые данные:

```
select d1.account_id, a1.user_id,  d1.created_at 
from account a1
join deposit d1 on a1.id=d1.account_id
join (
select a.user_id, min(d.created_at) as created_at
from account a
join deposit d on a.id=d.account_id
group by a.user_id)x on x.user_id=a1.user_id and x.created_at=d1.created_at
```

Фиддл [тут](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8ff407bf626fc5f1839a454745cf18f6)

Answer (score 3):

Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить DDL и образец вставки данных.

Предполагая, что MySQL версии 8.0

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
CREATE TABLE account (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, user_id INT);
INSERT INTO account (id, user_id) VALUES
(1, 2),
(2,12),
(3,13),
(4, 2),
(5, 2),
(6, 2);

CREATE TABLE deposit (id INT, account_id INT, created_at DATETIME, value DECIMAL(10,2)
,  INDEX (account_id), FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES account (id));
INSERT INTO deposit (id, account_id, created_at, value) VALUES
(1, 1,'2020-06-01 15:51:37',50.00),
(2, 1,'2020-06-05 13:05:25',20.00),
(3, 1,'2020-06-05 13:36:11',20.00),
(4, 2,'2020-06-16 12:34:04',70.00),
(5, 3,'2020-06-22 07:20:57',50.00),
(6, 4,'2020-05-30 08:25:56',30.00);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH rs AS 
(
    SELECT a.*, b.created_at
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY b.created_at) AS seq
    FROM account a INNER JOIN 
        deposit b ON a.id = b.account_id
)
SELECT id, user_id, created_at
FROM rs
WHERE seq = 1;
```

> Вывод

```
+----+---------+-------------------------+
| id | user_id |       created_at        |
+----+---------+-------------------------+
|  4 |       2 | 2020-05-30 08:25:56.000 |
|  2 |      12 | 2020-06-16 12:34:04.000 |
|  3 |      13 | 2020-06-22 07:20:57.000 |
+----+---------+-------------------------+
```

> MySQL 5.7

```
set @row_number := 0;
set @user_id := 0;

SELECT id, user_id, created_at FROM
(
SELECT @row_number := CASE
        WHEN @user_id = user_id 
        THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
    END AS seq,
    @user_id := user_id as user_id,
id, created_at
FROM (SELECT a.*, b.created_at 
       FROM account AS a INNER JOIN 
        deposit b ON a.id = b.account_id) as c
ORDER BY user_id, created_at ASC) as z
WHERE seq = 1;
```

Comment: Когда даёте ответ, необходимо внимательно читать вопрос. Вы группируете записи по `account_id`, хотя я явно написал, что мне нужно получить идентификатор счёта для каждого `user_id`. Если у одного `user_id` имеется 10 счётов, в результате я должен получить **только один**.

Comment: Спасибо за дополнительные разъяснения. Я обновил ответ.

Comment: На MySQL 5.7 ваш запрос не работает, ругается на некорректный синтаксис.

Comment: Я обновил ответ для MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Спасибо, а этот запрос работает, поставил вам плюс.

Comment: @HakuKimura. Рад слышать, что предлагаемое решение работает на вас. Пожалуйста, не забудьте пометить его как Ответ.

Comment: Всё же я принял ответ пользователя Novitskiy Denis, т.к. он написал работающий запрос раньше и в моём случае он более удобен. Хотя ваш вариант мне тоже понравился (особенно с рекурсией) и если бы была возможность, я бы оба ответа отметил, как принятые. 